# ObjectInputStream.readObject() on classes without SerialVersionUID

Tags: serialization

I have a base class (A) that implements serializable. This class has a generated SerailVersionUID but its child class (B) does not have serialVersionUID.

I have the following in place (the input stream contains objects of type B)

```
public Object getObject() throws...
{
  Object o = someObjectInputStream.readObject();
  return o;
}
```

I know that it is best practice to cast the object returned by readObject() but the casting is done on the returned object by the method that calls getObject();

**Querstion:**
Is it true that the returned object could be of either type A or B?
Is there any guarantee that the returned type is always B considering that it does not have a UID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it doesn't have a serialVersionUID has no bearing on what class you receive. That is determined solely by what class you sent. Your question doesn't really make sense.